# Is it possible to eagerly load the foreign key on a new object in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entities:

```
public class Seminar
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Meeting
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SeminarId { get; set; }
    public string ThirdPartyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Webinar Webinar { get; set; }
}
```

`Meeting` is related to `Seminar` by the `SeminarId` property (a foreign key).

The `ThirdPartyId` property (name changed to protect my interests) is populated after making a call to a third party API - it's the "link" to that system.

In order to make this call (in which we create the same object on that system), we need the `Title` and `Description` information from the seminar associated with the meeting.

So let's say I create a new meeting like so:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    Meeting meeting = new Meeting
    {
        SeminarId = 5 // this would normally be loaded from elsewhere, obviously
    };

    // Load the meeting.Webinar property somehow here

    m_thirdPartyApiClient.CreateMeeting(meeting); // Uses meeting.Webinar.Title and meeting.Webinar.Description

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

What I'd like to do is to load the foreign key property on `meeting` before calling the third party API or `SaveChanges`. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just call the database for the seminar by its id?

Comment: Well then I'd have to modify the api client and pass in the meeting *and* the seminar. I've considered that, but it's not ideal.

Comment: No then just assign the returned seminar to the virtual seminar field

Comment: You can't assign to a virtual field, can you?

Comment: Why not. As long as the setter is public theres no problem

Comment: How is EF (or anything else for that matter) supposed to know which seminar you intend to associate with the meeting, unless you tell it. You'll have to get the seminar's id from the DB and give it to the newly created meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the database for the Seminar by its id and Assign it to the meeting like `Meeting.Seminar = dbSeminar`. To answer your comment, `virtual` just says that this method/property may be over written by a inheriting class and when overwritten to use the inheriting class's prop/method *even when the ref is of type base class* as long as the actual type is inheriting class.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this and it didn't work before. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you add the entity object to the corresponding `DbSet`, you can load any reference property by using [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry%602.Load);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method like this:

```
Meeting meeting = new Meeting
{
    SeminarId = 5 // this would normally be loaded from elsewhere, obviously
};
db.Meetings.Add(meeting);
// meeting.Webinar is still null
db.Entry(meeting).Reference(m => m.Webinar).Load();
// meeting.Webinar is populated
```